# Easy way to fill a geometric figure in Assembly

Tags: assembly, x86-16, fasm

Is there a easy to fill a geometric figure like these one? :
[image]

My code:

```
org 100h

;320 x 200

;video mode
mov ah, 4Fh
mov al, 2
mov bx, 13h
int 10h
;video mode

triangle_a:
 mov [x], 100
 mov [y], 100
 mov [size], 10
 mov cx, [x]
 mov dx, [y]

 horizontal_line:
  call pixel
  inc cx
  dec [size]
  jnz horizontal_line

 mov [size], 10
 vertical_line:
  call pixel
  dec dx
  dec [tam]
  jnz vertical_line

 mov [size], 10
 mov cx, [x]
 mov dx, [y]
 slanted_line:
  call pixel
  dec dx
  inc cx
  dec [size]
  jnz slanted_line


pixel:
  mov ah, 0ch
  mov al, 5
  mov bh, 0
  int 10h
ret
fim:
 mov ah, 4Ch
 int 21h

ret


x   rw 1
y   rw 1
size rw 1
```

Everything needs to be fasm compatible, and if there isn't a easy what is the better approach to do in this case?
At this point im just writing for the stackoverflow algorithm because I have anything else to say.

Comment: See e.g. [this](http://www.hugi.scene.org/online/coding/hugi%2017%20-%20cotriang.htm) for info on how you can rasterize any triangle. It doesn't contain any assembly code, but assuming that you understand the algorithm you should be able to implement it yourself.

Comment: You could use VBE to draw triangles.  I recall that it supports drawing polygons.

Comment: I am only allowed to use FASM.

Comment: VBE is a set of extentions provided by the video card BIOS - not an external library. Whether it actually would be easier to use those than to just write your own triangle rasterizer is a different matter.

Comment: The obvious way would be nested loops that loop from the left-most column to the right-most column of the triangle within each row.  Then the horizontal line at the bottom isn't special, it's just part of filling rows.